# How can I migrate Linux user account To Active Directory while preserving all user settings

Tags: linux, active-directory

How can I add a Linux user to an active directory account
and keep all of the settings / profile from the Linux account?

In other words, how can I add a specific Linux user to AD so that when I login as the AD user, I have all the same settings as the original Linux user?

Up until now I used, in a terminal for the local Linux user,

```
sudo realm join <domain> --user=<AD user> -U <administrator>
```

I end up with a *new* user `/home/<domain>/<AD user>/`, but the new AD user does not have any settings from the Linux user.